# Laravel Filament. Open record for editing after ReplicateAction

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have actions like this in a resource (replicate and edit):

```
public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->columns([
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('base_currency.name')->sortable(),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('target_currency.name')->sortable(),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('rate'),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')->dateTime()->sortable(),
            Tables\Columns\IconColumn::make('is_current')
                ->boolean()
                ->trueIcon('heroicon-o-badge-check')
                ->falseIcon('heroicon-o-x-circle'),
        ])
        ->defaultSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->filters([
            Tables\Filters\SelectFilter::make('base_currency_id')
                ->options(Currency::getAll()->mapWithKeys(function ($currency, $key) {
                    return [$currency->id => $currency->code];
                }))
                ->label('Base currency'),
            Tables\Filters\SelectFilter::make('target_currency_id')
                ->options(Currency::getAll()->mapWithKeys(function ($currency, $key) {
                    return [$currency->id => $currency->code];
                }))
                ->label('Target currency'),
            Tables\Filters\Filter::make('is_current')
                ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('is_current', true))
                ->label('Current only')
                ->default(),
        ])
        ->actions([
            Tables\Actions\ReplicateAction::make('replicate')
                ->beforeReplicaSaved(
                    function (Model $replica): void {
                        $replica->is_current = true;
                        ExchangeRate::query()->where([
                            'base_currency_id' => $replica->base_currency_id,
                            'target_currency_id' => $replica->target_currency_id,
                            'is_current' => true,
                        ])
                            ->update(['is_current' => false]);
                    }
                )
                ->after(fn (Model $record) => route('exchange-rates.edit', $record)),
            Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
        ])
        ->bulkActions([
            Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
        ]);
}
```

It is necessary in after to make it so that after replicate the record, the transition to the page with editing is carried out, similar to the EditAction action, how to do this?

`after(fn (Model $record) => route('exchange-rates.edit', $record))`

This doesn't work because no registered route

Comment: This means after edit it should redirect to the Edit exchange rates page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect any action you need to add redirection code in the `->action()`

```php
Tables\Actions\Action::make('Go to Edit')
    ->color('success')
    ->icon('heroicon-o-link')
    ->action(fn (Model $record) => redirect()->route('filament.resources.todos.edit', $record)),
```

and you already know how to check the route list in the laravel.

```
php artisan route:list
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not include, or worse, reintroduce noise such as emoji or 'thanks' into posts. Keep content focused. See the [help] for more info on what kind of content belongs in posts on Stack Overflow.